# How to use wp.hooks.addAction() in React JS/Gutenberg?

Tags: javascript, hooks, block-editor

I am able to successfully use `wp.hooks.applyFilters()` and `wp.hooks.addFilter()`, but I'm not able to render a React Component using `wp.hooks.addAction()`. However, the `console.log()` runs just fine within the callback for an action. This is my code:

```
import { createHooks } from '@wordpress/hooks';

let globalHooks = createHooks();

const Header = () => {
    return (
        <h1>Header Component</h1>
    );
}

const RevisedHeader = () => {
    return (
        <h1>Revised Header Component</h1>
    )
}

export default class App extends Component {

    constructor( props ) {
        super();

        globalHooks.addFilter( 'replace_header', 'revisedHeaderCallback', this.revisedHeaderCallback );
        globalHooks.addAction( 'after_replace_header', 'afterRevisedHeaderCallback', this.afterRevisedHeaderCallback );
    };

    revisedHeaderCallback( header ) {
        return <RevisedHeader />;
    }

    afterRevisedHeaderCallback() {
        return <RevisedHeader />;
    }

    render() {

        return(
            <div className="App">
                { globalHooks.applyFilters( 'replace_header', <Header /> ) }
                { globalHooks.doAction( 'after_replace_header' ) }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### How to use `wp.hooks.addAction`?

It's basically like so, just like you've attempted:

```js
// Hook to the hook_name action.
wp.hooks.addAction( 'hook_name', 'namespace', function(){
    console.log( 'Foo Bar' );
} );

// Trigger the hook_name action.
wp.hooks.doAction( 'hook_name' );
```

Or for hooks which provide one or more parameters to the callback:

```js
// Hook to the hook_name action.
wp.hooks.addAction( 'hook_name', 'namespace', function( a, b ){
    console.log( a, b );
} );

// Trigger the hook_name action.
wp.hooks.doAction( 'hook_name', 'foo', [ 'bar', 'boo' ] );
```

> I am able to successfully use `wp.hooks.applyFilters()` and
> `wp.hooks.addFilter()`, but I'm not able to render a React Component
> using `wp.hooks.addAction()`.

**The problem is *not* with your code**, but it's because unlike the `wp.hooks.applyFilters` function, `wp.hooks.doAction` *simply returns nothing* or it returns `undefined`:

- Here an element is returned and React later rendered the element:

  ```js
  { globalHooks.applyFilters( 'replace_header', <Header /> ) }
  ```

  The above translates to this, which renders an element:

  ```js
  { <RevisedHeader /> }
  ```
- Here `undefined` is always returned, so no elements are rendered:

  ```js
  { globalHooks.doAction( 'after_replace_header' ) }
  { globalHooks.doAction( 'after_replace_header', <Header /> ) }
  ```

  The above translates to this, which "does nothing good":

  ```js
  { undefined }
  ```

So once again, the problem is that `wp.hooks.doAction` *always* returns an `undefined` even if for example your `afterRevisedHeaderCallback` function actually returns an element or component.

Hence, use `globalHooks.applyFilters` (or rather `wp.hooks.applyFilters`) if you wish to render React elements/components like so:

```js
{ globalHooks.applyFilters( 'hook_name', <FooBar /> ) }
```

### UPDATE

> then what purpose does doAction() serve? What would be the use
> case?

To do other actions than what you've tried to - `{ globalHooks.doAction( 'after_replace_header' ) }` (here you attempted to *render an element or a component*). So you could instead perform AJAX requests, modify an object (e.g. an `Array`), etc. You could also run [`ReactDOM.render`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render) from a callback hooked via `wp.hooks.addAction`, but (as you may already know) the element container has to be already attached to the DOM. But one thing *for sure*, `wp.hooks.doAction` always returns `undefined`.

**Example for modifying an object**

The callback (in your component):

```js
afterRevisedHeaderCallback( arr ) {
    arr.push( 'bar' );
}
```

It's hooked here:

```js
globalHooks.addAction( 'after_replace_header', 'afterRevisedHeaderCallback', this.afterRevisedHeaderCallback );
```

Your component's `render` method:

```js
render() {
    let a = [ 'foo' ];
    globalHooks.doAction( 'after_replace_header', a );

    return(
        <div className="App">
            { globalHooks.applyFilters( 'replace_header', <Header /> ) }
            { a.join(', ') }
        </div>
    );
}
```

### UPDATE 2

Just like in PHP in WordPress, `do_action_ref_array` and `do_action` returns nothing/`NULL`, but `apply_filters_ref_array` and `apply_filters` both return whatever returned by the callback to a filter/hook, which yes, could be `NULL`.

And if you're skeptical about the `undefined` returned by `wp.hooks.doAction`, then check out the source [here](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/hooks/src/createRunHook.js).

### UPDATE 3

Based on the example in **UPDATE** above, you could actually render the element/component this way...

The callback (in your component):

```js
afterRevisedHeaderCallback( arr ) {
//  arr = [ <RevisedHeader /> ]; // doesn't work
    arr[0] = <RevisedHeader />;  // works fine
}
```

Your component's `render` method:

```js
render() {
    let el = [ <Header /> ];
    globalHooks.doAction( 'after_replace_header', el );

    return(
        <div className="App">
            { globalHooks.applyFilters( 'replace_header', <Header /> ) }
            { el }
        </div>
    );
}
```

I think you could understand the trick in that approach?

Comment: then what what purpose does `doAction()` serve? What would be the use case?

Comment: Check the "UPDATE" part in the answer.

Comment: And you could override the `doAction` prototype, but that's more to a dirty hack, so I'm not going to add that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

applyFilters in JS

```
(function( $ ) {
    'use strict';
    $(function() {

        var cars = wp.hooks.applyFilters( 'carlist', ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"]);
        console.log("cars======="+cars);

    });
})( jQuery );
```

Enqueue addFilter

```
function wpdocs_scripts_method() {
    $src = 'jQuery(document).ready(function($) { wp.hooks.addFilter( "carlist", "carlist", function(cars){ var cars = ["Benz"];  return cars; }); });';
    wp_add_inline_script( 'jquery', $src );

}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_scripts_method' );
```

Check console for the log